# Proving the given inequality using the concept of increasing-decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I want to prove $x-(x^3/3)<\tan^{-1} x<x$ for all real $x>0$.

I have done the following:

[image]

If it could be proved that y has a maximum value of 0 at x=0 the first part of the given inequality can be proved. But, it is coming out to be a point of inflection. Is this method wrong? Please give me some hints on how to do this problem.

Sorry for the terrible handwriting.

Comment: The hint in your title has to do with increasing/decreasing of function, i.e. the sign of the first derivative.  Note that the three expressions $x-(x^3/3), \tan^{-1} x, x$ start out being equal at $x=0$.  Have you considered what happens to their differences as $x$ increases?  I.e. take a derivative of $x - \tan^{-1} x$ to see if the difference increases.

Answer (score 2):

As $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{-x^4}{1+x^2} <0$$ the function $$y(x) =x-\frac{x^3}{3} -\arctan x$$ is monotone decreasing hence $$y(x)< y(0) =0$$ for all $x>0.$

Comment: I suspect the other side of the "pinching", $\arctan x < x$, is easier to establish by a similar argument.